# php regular expression: how to correctly escape characters?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How to write preg_match, to match string `*My*` ?

This doesn't work:

```
$ptn = "/\*(.*)\*/";
$str = "*My*";
preg_match($ptn, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

because it outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => *My*
    [1] => *My*
)
```

instead of:

```
Array
(
    [0] => *My*
    [1] => My
)
```

Comment: Your code seems to have the desired output.

Comment: No, there is difference. I need to extract "My" alone, without surrounding "*".

Comment: Yes, check Marc B's answer below. Your code seems to do what you want. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pgr-asi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine here:

```
php > preg_match('/\*(.*)\*/', '*My*', $matches);
php > var_dump($matches);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "*My*"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "My"
}
```

Remember that the `$matches` array will ALWAYS contain the entire matched string in position 0, then the individal matches in slots 1+.

Comment: I used a [website](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm) to check the regex and it seems it was calculating it wrong.

Comment: better report a bug to that site, then.